Export Plotly figure to show in ReactMarkdown
I want to create an interactive graph in Python using Plotly, and then export the graph (or html) to view in ReactMarkdown. One of the bigger issues is that I don't have access to the html file for this. A different script is run by someone else to convert the Python code to ReactMarkdown. This is part of a company-wide challenge, so I don't have access or know anything about the script. I believe it is using React Markdown, as html isn't showing up.
I was able to do this with static graphs using imgur to host, but I can't seem to figure out a way to do it with interactive graphs in Plotly. I also tried the instructions on this tutorial, but couldn't get it working. Any ideas?
Example code:
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Create a basic Plotly figure
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(y=[2, 3, 1])])

# Save the figure as an HTML div
fig.write_html("plotly_chart.html", full_html=False)


what do you get from the graph export from python? Is it that plotly_chart.html file?

Yes, all of my code is in Python and the chart gets transferred through React Markdown onto a webpage

"A different script is run by someone else to convert the Python code to ReactMarkdown.", we need more info, please edit your post and add all the relevant details.

Edited, but I truly don't know anything about the script that is being run. It's for a company challenge, and I just want to be able to show my interactive plots once all of the code is converted.

so you are able to make plotly_chart.html file, you need to know how to give this to your company,to some script which you don't know about?

Until you add details about what documents you are allowed or required to provide, it seems impossible to answer this question. If you are only allowed to pass markdown or plain html documents without scripts, interactivity is not achievable. Otherwise, answers to this question may help.

i came up with this searching for similar problem ,Link(Check with this) - https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/

Since you need to embed a Plotly interactive graph in ReactMarkdown without direct HTML access, you can use a workaround to display the chart in React. Here’s how you can approach it: Generate a JSON Representation of the Plotly Graph: You can use Plotly’s to json() method to export the chart as JSON data, which can then be used to render the chart in React. Render the JSON in React using Plotly’s JavaScript Library: With the JSON data, you can render the chart in React by feeding it into Plotly’s react library. Here’s how you can do it:
Step 1: Generate the Plotly JSON in Python,
save your Plotly figure data as JSON:
#This is Python
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import json

# Create a basic Plotly figure
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(y=[2, 3, 1])])

# Convert figure to JSON format
plotly_json = fig.to_json()

# Save JSON to a file, which React can read and use for rendering
with open("plotly_chart.json", "w") as f:
  json.dump(plotly_json, f)

Step 2: Load the JSON in React and Render with Plotly.js
in your React component:
Load the JSON Data: Use fetch to load the JSON file that was saved by the Python script.
Use Plotly to Render the Chart: With Plotly’s JavaScript library, render the chart using the JSON data.
Here’s an example React component to handle it:
# This is JavaScript
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Plotly from 'plotly.js';

const PlotlyChart = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
  // Fetch the JSON data generated by Plotly
  fetch('/path/to/plotly_chart.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    Plotly.newPlot('plotlyChart', parsedData.data, parsedData.layout);
    });
}, []);

return <div id="plotlyChart" />;
};

export default PlotlyChart;

Explanation
Python: Exports the chart as JSON, which captures all Plotly configurations.
React: Reads and parses the JSON, then uses Plotly’s newPlot function to render the interactive chart on a <div>. There may be some bugs in this code as I had to move 4 spaces the whole time and no auto-indentations so check the indentations and correct if needed. Hope this helped!
